# What would be the side effects on the life of a person becoming indestructible?

Tags: biology

I have a rather odd setting where one of my characters gets cursed/blessed with indestructibility, more specifically all of her cells have stopped degenerating and dividing and they all are now immune to any known forms of damage. (but this only applies to living cells and bone tissues, so nails and hair are still destructible). Also the person is still very capable of feeling pain.

What effects would such a curse/blessing would have on the human body?

To give you a few points that I am interested in:

- would she be in constant pain?
- would she go mad?
- would learning new things be impeded?

Bonus points for any side effects described not mentioned above.

Comment: How can she feel pain if she isn't damaged?

Comment: Are these cells also immortal or , as some answers point out, can they die?

Comment: You can still "kill" them with fire, enough heat will denature the extracellular matrix proteins holding their cells to each other, they will literally slowly collapse into a pile of healthy yet unconnected cell, which is probably the most disturbing death I can imagine. The individual thinking creature is completely dead even if all their cells are still around, humans are more than just cells they are cells in a specific pattern.

Comment: If apoptosis (programmed cell death) is no longer possible, she will be highly susceptible to cancer. If cancer can't kill her, it can at least cause pain and impair organ function.

Comment: @LarsH if cells are no longer dividing, she'd also be immune to cancer.

Comment: @Delioth Yeah, fair point, especially if you consider the cancer cells to be still "her cells."

Comment: You have a very interesting question!  As written, it is too broad for this forum.  (As a reminder, questions should be limited in focus to a single worldbuilding problem or issue.  You're asking for a list!) See the [tour] and [help] for a refresher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres several things that will happen.

- your character will stop eating and drinking. Since the cells dont degenerate they cannot be malnourished, which is a form of damage to your body. So some kind of nebulous energy has to come from somewhere to power the cells.
- because of the previous point any toilet behaviour will be directly correlated to how much you are active. More active means more waste products created that the body needs to get rid off.
- your character will stop feeling pain except for heat, cold and pressure. "Normal" pain is based on cells getting damaged and products of that cell reaching a nerve ending that reacts to these products, warning that you have damaged cells in the area. The sensations of heat, cold and pressure are warning signals that already hurt before you receive damage in order for the person to react and prevent damage to his/her body.
- simultaneously with the previous point the character will never heat up or cool down, as that prevents the body from optimal performance by disrupting and destroying certain enzymes and other bodily products and reactions. Its the heat/cold difference that your body will warn for. So her body will remain at perfect temperature at all times, even when wearing a ski jacket in summer or birthday suit in winter.
- the character will no longer age (duh). The cells cannot deteriorate because of genetic defects accumulating in the cells.
- the character will no longer be sick ever again. Viruses and bacteria simply cannot create the damage necessary to make you sick, and without the necessary cell divisions your body will no longer be able to create an immune reaction anyway.

And one last thing. Dont throw her into a star or black hole, she'd never be able to get out or move her body ever again while in so much pain her body wouldnt know what to do with it. Thats just cruel.

Comment: There's nothing that would prevent the body from heating up or cooling down, it just wouldn't damage the cells. Enzymes could still denature, as those are nonliving proteins. Also, there are many kinds of pain that don't require mechanical destruction of cells, so pain is still very much on the table for this person.

Comment: @NuclearWang If the enzymes are allowed to denature without damaging the cells, then so can the mytochondria be destroyed without damaging the cells. No need for the processes they provide if it can be done with the curse/blessing right? Cell walls? Just keep them together with the magic! If you allow enzymes to denature through heat or cold it would mean you would allow most of the cell to be completely gone and replaced by magic as well. As for pain receptors, the only one's I missed were chemical one's.

Comment: @Demigan ... animal cells don't have cell walls. Not that it changes anything - we're still talking about pure magic. Any meaningful "indestructibility" of cells I can think of mean you're dead. The same mechanisms that cells need to transfer materials in and out of the cells are what's exploited by viruses and most bacterial toxins in the first place. What happens to an "indestructible" cell when it can't get its sugar from the blood?

Comment: @Luaan Meant to say Cell Membrane. As for Viruses and Bacteria, they wouldn't be able to cause harm to the cell even if they did get in. So the cells would still be able to get nutrients.

Comment: @Demigan Even if you could somehow prevent the viruses or bacteria from doing damage, they would start accumulating in the cells. Bacteria would feed on the nutrients coming into the cells (the same way our sybmiotic relationship with mitochondria probably started), and viruses would just clutter everything up. Even with no damage being done, your metabolism would slowly grind to a halt, and if your magical invulnerability kept on, all of your cells would be incapable of actually doing anything. Maybe your brain might be isolated for a while, but what does a brain do without oxygen?

Answer (score 17):

The first immediately obvious consequence is that the person will be skinless in no more than a few days.... The outer layer of the skin is made of dead cells which are shed continuously and replaced by new cells from the basal layer. Once the cornified outer layer is gone (no more than a few days) the inner soft layer will be exposed to the elements and will be damaged in a very short time.

Comment: They would look like they got sunburned, but they won't take any damage... even while in the sun...

Comment: @TobyB: The question says that the **cells** are immune to damage. I am saying that the basal epidermal layer is soft and moist and will tear apart. The cells may survive all right, but the non-living collagen matrix will not.

Comment: okay so I researched a bit the human skin and it turns out that the epiderm (the outermost skin layer) is not fully made out of dead cells 80% is dead cells but the remaining 20% would still be living and protecting you from the worst of it, but I also found out that you would dehydrate faster and be more susceptibile to infections :(

Comment: @TobyB: The epidermis is made up of a lower layer of living cells (the basal layer) and an upper layer of cornified dead cells. The outer layer is continuously interacting with the environment and is lost due to abrasions etc. The lower layer replenishes it by dividing and pushing new cells outwars. The lower layer is not intended to be exposed to mechanical and environmental stress.

Comment: still, it is far better than exposing your dermis + you would still have a thin layer of  die-ing cells, partially filled with keratine still attached to you that are now immortal. (that helps too).

Comment: This will apply to hair as well, so hairless on top of skinless.

Comment: Their cells won't be damaged, however without the outer layer of skin they will be in constant state of hypersensitivity, Imagine the sensitivity of a healing burn all the time on every inch of skin. They will probably need to live in tub of saline solution just to stand it.

Comment: Also they will loose cells, the cells will be healthy but detached from the body as the extracellular matrix is unsufficnt to hold them together against abrasion, so they will slowly wear away, starting with their feet.

Comment: The cells can't be damaged, though, which means that anything that triggers off of "cell damage" won't happen.  You'll have an absurdly heightened sense of touch there, but no pain, and pain is about detecting damage.

Comment: @BenBarden Pain is about detecting impact (pressure), temperature or compounds given off by damage.  But would damaged extracellular matrix be sufficient to generate the "damage" pain?  Would the pressure with no armor of dead skins be enough to trigger "pressure" pain?  Would the lack of insulating skin generate temperature gradients steep enough to trigger the "heat" pain?

Comment: @Yakk thanks to burn victims we know the answer is yes, exposure of dermal cells leads to hypersensitivity. It will also be extremely itchy.

Answer (score 7):

> all of her cells have stopped degenerating and dividing and they all are now immune to any known forms of damage.

Our immune system is based on rapid multiplication of the lymphocytes as reaction to an infection. Since you are removing the capability to have cell division, you are negating the possibility to have immune reaction. But the cells won't sustain any damage: thus your character will experience an overlapping of the symptoms of all the diseases/infection he/she will catch over time, with no hope of healing. Just picking the overlap of 4 not so uncommon infections:

1. running nose from a cold
2. diarrhea from a food poisoning
3. muscular relaxation induced by botulism
4. muscular spams from tetanic infection.

I am confident it would be a hell of a life.

Neurons do not multiplicate in any case, they just rearrange correction. So this power won't affect the learning capability, as long as some other disease won't interfere with learning.

Nails and hair grow because some cells are dividing. With division gone, they would stop growing, too.

Comment: All of those symptoms are a result of cellular damage and disfunction caused by toxins or viral infection. Indestructible cells seem unlikely to suffer from any of those at all. What you _might_ have to worry about are parasites or fungal infections that can _impair_ without explicitly causing or needing to cause cellular damage. Have a think about what an eternity with [filiariasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filariasis) would be like.

Comment: Yes but you do have lymphocytes in your system and wouldn't many of these disseases need to feed on your cells one way or another or on the nutrients on your body, couldn't you just starve yourself for a month and be rid of any if not all diseases?

Comment: The "are now immune to any known forms of damage." completely precludes viral infection. Bacterial infection would be hard to gauge.

Comment: @Ash, usually cells explodes when infected by a virus because the virus steers the cell in producing itself. If the cell does not explode because it cannot be damaged, this won't preclude massive production of the virus replica.

Comment: @L.Dutch The virus has to punch a hole through the protein sheath to infect the cell in the first place, if the cells are immune to _any damage at all_ that won't be possible.

Comment: @L.Dutch Also, how could you get a tetanic infection, the only way I might see it happen if you ingest rust,but even then it's debatable...

Comment: @TobyB, Clostridium tetani is a common soil bacterium. Ingesting anything contaminated by soil can lead to infection.

Comment: It would seem that only bacterial infection would be problematic, viral infections need to modify the inner workings of a cell to multiply and parasites need a lot of food to sustain themselves + you can always drink something like cyannide to clean your gut of any life and then repopulate it with good bacteria (infections in other places seem unlikely or just unsusteinable)

Comment: @TobyB I thought this person still felt pain? You *could* drink cyanide to clean yourself, but I hardly think it would be pleasant. There is probably some intermediate means of purgning your system

Comment: @Nyakouai True, but any substance that could numb your senses and kill everything in your gut would do, but I digress to your more humane solutions :)

Comment: fungal infection would also be an issue. Many fungi burrow between cells.

Comment: @Nyakouai You can still technically feel pain, but any pain that would be coming out of cell damage is skipped entirely.  Is there any pain that doesn't follow from cell damage?

Comment: @BenBarden That's what I thought in the first place, but I think there are a lot of things that are still painful. Pinching a nerve will still hurt - so headache from hypertension, random misplaced bump are still a thing. You could technically get cut without cell being damaged, so still pain on this side... The definition of the invulnerability is a bit blurry here so I'm not sure where to stop. But pain definitely still exists.

Comment: @StarfishPrime The fungal infections presumably eat cells and other biological matter in order to feed themselves?

Comment: I would be worried about viruses already in your cells.  Most people have these.  Our immune system detects cells which know they are infected and kills them.  After this change, when a virus in a cell turns the cell into a mass virus producer, the immune system is useless against it.  On the other hand, the virus cannot spread to other cells.  So you'll shed the virus a lot, and waste metabolic energy on it?

Comment: @Yakk your bloodstream is full of nutrients. Not sure if there are any fungi that can subsist on that, but it isn't beyond the realms of possibility.

Comment: @Yakk infected cells release viruses by exploding. Presumably in this case they just get choken up with viral proteins but don't burst and spread viral particles.

Comment: @StarfishPrime It's thought that mitochondia might have originally been bacteria that started living in our cells (either through being eaten and not properly digested, or gaining access otherwise). So it's very likely possible for a bacterium to subsist on the nutrients in human bloodstream. Those would build up very quickly with no way of fighting their growth - regardless of if it happens inside or outside of cells, this would probably be a problem.

Answer (score 7):

Depending how we interpret the "known" in "immune to any known forms of damage" we get a very different picture:

- if we assume that the "known" means damage that has previously been experienced by their body then the first bacterial infection they get that they hadn't experienced before will kill them. Their body can no longer adapt to novel toxins and their immune system cannot create new antibodies to kill off the new invader.
- if we assume that "known" means everything the person doing the cursing knows is possible then it becomes a story element that you can have endless fun with.

Regardless of the interpretation the character won't be able to breed, no more [meiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis). Their teeth will eventually wear out regardless of how well they try to care for them as enamel is never renewed, that will get extremely painful. Existing injuries will never heal, *at all*, if they're bleeding even in the slightest went the curse is placed they will bleed out and die, period. Any corrective surgery, like having those broken teeth out, will either be impossible or lethal.

No-one knows how much storage a human brain can handle but eventually they're going to start suffering some form of dementia, not sure what that would look like though.

Comment: I did not think about the breeding part and it makes a lot of sense now, as for the teeth, you could just coat them in something and never be bothered again (the fleshy bits are immune to damage)

Comment: @TobyB Yeah you could probably coat them in some way to keep the air out, you wouldn't damage the flesh but the nerve irritation isn't caused by damage so if you didn't find a coating that worked you'd have episodes of extreme pain at intervals when the coasting wears through.

Comment: Fingernails eventually wear away and all the blood leaks out

Comment: eventually start suffering some form of dementia - if their cells become resistant to any changes, then that's going to happen pretty quickly - wouldn't be able to form new memories, though old ones would remain intact.

Comment: @Baldrickk It's thought that memory is stored as connections between neurons; those might still be able to form and break even if the cells are "indestructible" - unless you outright fix the cells to make them unable to change in any way, which would be indistinguishable from death anyway (apart from the curious fact that the body wouldn't seem to decay even after decades).

Comment: That would be an interesting way to kill someone - by making them invincible.

Answer (score 3):

Blood related problems:

blood is full of oxygen and sugar - so it make good growing ground for many invaders (fungi, yeast, ...)

As there is only so much blood cells (and new would never grow), there inevitably became moment, when they would not be able eat and process all invaders. And those invaders would grow, so at some time there will be so much, that some veins would stuck with them. No problem per se, as none cells would die, but some  cells would be starving without supply of oxygen and sugar. And at some point they would just stop working (until refilled again), so muscles would stop moving and brain would be paralysed too. (Well until some drastical cleaning would be done, which would totally destroy everything destroyable and leave only the living body. And it would need be so drastical to decompose all those (now dead) invaders to such small pieces, that they could be trasported to organs, that could eject them out of the body.

If it would be done late, that the person would be paralysed for long time, until osmosis push a lot of oxygen and suger (should be artifically added to body) to the heart and it start pumping blood around again to distribute food for other cells too and "restart" rest of the body. Hungry cells around the way to heart would not be helping, as they would eat much supply just to be able spend it without any possible effect.

Also there should be proper eating, as the person would survive without food, but the muscle cells would not have chemicals to make movement and so undereating would paralayse that person too (and brain burns so much energy/food, that the starving would came fast if eating/drinking was improper). Drinking also need be done otherwise the blood would lose watter and stop circulating at some point (first blocking small veins, then larger and starve muscle cells as before to paralysis).

Pain may became problem too, as constant pain is suppressed and ignored after some time - the pain limit grows higher and higher - and well my leg is in pain for year, so what, it is no longer problem for me, just feature. I know, I should do something with it, maybe tomorrow, or next week or next millenium, but it is not so bad to force me do something JUST NOW. And I so dislike the taste of strong hydroxide/acid, which could solve it, so lets it wait just some time more ... I have still write some article on web and see the movie and the serial did not ended yet ...

Comment: You made a fair point with blood drying up...

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that this world has more than a little magic involved. In that case I would suggest you read the manga **"UQ Holder"** and checking out the character **Karin**.

Karin was cursed with absolute invulnerability over 2000 years before the story takes place. I thought about her when I read your question since you specifically mentioned being able to feel pain, which is normally a result of damage, which your character should now be immune to. Karin can feel pain however, because her form of immortality is one that messes with reality to litterally **remove** damage instantly. In once scene she is being cut with a knife, and you never see even the slightest hint of damage, but the guy who is cutting her notes that he can feel the resistance of cutting flesh, and she is clearly feeling pain as if she is being cut.

Anyways, I think her case would be good inspiration for your idea.

PS: The title, UQ Holder, is kind of a play on words in Japanese. 悠久 (yûkyû) means "eternity" so the title kinda means "Eternity Holder", and it is the name of the main *goog guy* organization in the story, which is made up of people who are immortal (to different degrees; you have Karin that really cannot die, and you have a guy who simply won't age but could easily be killed by decapitation)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your character description, I will make some detailed assumptions:

1)Basically the living cells have become indestructible particles like atoms (under normal circumstances). I assume this power extends to all the tissues as a whole as well. Otherwise you can cut the tissue by simply separating the adjacent cells with sufficient force.

Effect: Character will start losing sense of pain slowly and steadily. The biological process and nerve reaction will still be there, but the brain will start ignoring the signals. The pain becomes a false trigger as there was no corresponding damage. On a long term, this might lead to desensitization and lack of empathy, slowly devolving into lack of certain emotions. This includes fear of death.

2) No cell division = no new cells at all

Effect: No reproductive capabilities may lead to degeneration of certain instincts, like losing interest in reproduction and related physiological and psychological phenomenon.

3) Despite being indestructible, the cells still need energy to function without which, the cells will enter a super dormant state, and wake up again after energy is available.

Effect: Most biological functions will continue. Character will experience hunger and thirst as well as the need to sleep due to getting tired. Combined with the above effects of losing some emotions and instincts, character may develop dependency on certain things. For a positive tone, this would be highly exhausting activities in terms of both physical and mental, otherwise character wouldn't need or be able to eat and sleep properly. For a negative tone, heavy addictions to junk food and/or drugs and other substances.

4) Cells do not die or divide, but the organs still produce the various chemicals, and body still accumulates certain substances over time

Effect: The character can easily "suffer" high blood pressure if consuming too much salt and fats primarily because the fat accumulates but the skin doesn't stretch and grow, kidney stone or other such problems caused by accumulation of external substances within the body. Of course these problems can easily be cured by strong medications easily since there should be no side-effects.

5) Long Life span

Effect: After a number of years, character will start suffering memory losses, because the brain has a maximum capacity for information.

Comment: Reproductive instincts evolved to facilitate reproduction, but your body doesn't know that. Just because your efforts are futile doesn't mean your instincts will disappear - they're baked in. Kidney stones are actually a very interesting idea - if the stone grows too big, it could completely block the flow of urine, eventually stopping the kidneys entirely (as neither the vessels nor kidneys can "be damaged", the pressure would increase until the filtration no longer works). Even though the cells can't be damaged, the build up of metabolic byproducts would eventually stop all metabolism.

Answer (score 0):

**Some quick observations and outcomes.**

1. No more hair. You say the hair can be damaged, but since your cells cant divide that means no more hair after it is lost the first time.
2. No new memories after a while, [because your brain will eventually become full, since there is a theoretical maxiumum capacity for your brain](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-is-the-memory-capacity/).
3. No more reproduction. Obviously producing sperm and eggs as a process has stopped since they involve division.

Comment: You wouldn't have new memories assuming there's no garbage collector getting rid of old memories. I don't think we know enough about how memory works to assume memories are only ever added (there are certainly indications in both directions). Unless the immunity to damage also prevents normal cell functioning of course, in which case you wouldn't be able to form new memories period, right away.

Answer (score 0):

"What are the side-effects" questions *really* depend on the precise nature of how something is implemented.  The answer can be just about anything.

For example, given one reading of the curse, the individual would become the world's worst Flu carrier.  Influenza doesn't actually damage the cell walls.  It gets up close enough that the cell chooses to try to capture it, pinching off a lysome around the virus, then pumping it full of enzymes and acids.  Influenza is actually "designed" to detect this, unfurling a grappling hook like protien which sticks into the edge of the lysome and then pulls the flu out.  Technically this isn't the cell wall being damaged.  Even if it was considered damage, you're in real trouble because the cells will get filled with unbreakable lysomes.

So as a result, the flu can infect a cell without actually damaging the cell wall much.  It does its damage after being "trapped" by our cell's defenses.  Now it's put its DNA in your cell, making virus proteins.  Your immune system isn't going to be able to do anything about this, for the reasons mentioned in other answers.  As a result, every cell of your respiratory tract is going to get infected and start producing viruses at full speed!

Of course that's just one reading on the curse.  There's myrad others.

Comment: Viruses cannot make new proteins without damaging the inner workings of a cell, they need to attack either the mitocondria or the nucleus or some component of the cell, viruses work by rerwiting the dna code of a cell to produce more viruses, so no that will not happen.

Comment: @TobyB Except that the cell *also* needs to "attack" the nucleus. To create proteins, the DNA must be deconstructed, copied, and rebuilt again. If you allow this to happen, then viruses must also still be capable of doing the same thing. If you don't allow this to happen, your subject is dead anyway. I doubt there's any way in which you could make "cells indestructible" while keeping the person working and alive without just magically handwaving all the problems.

Comment: Animal cells don't have cell walls. But the point is moot anyway - it's not like viruses destroy anything to gain access to the cell - they just exploit the ways the cells bring materials in and out. If you disable this, you kill the person anyway. But within the constraints you used, the virus might be able to gain access to the cell, but it cannot get out - that requires the cell to essentially explode, which an indestructible membrane wouldn't allow to happen. Most viruses don't have the keys to get out the way they came in, so to speak.

Comment: @TobyB That is why I posted this answer.  The *precice* nature of how you go about things matters.  You have to define what "damage" means, and probably define how it happens.  Defending DNA from damage is actually a challenge life has being working at for hundreds of millions of years.  It's not easy... in fact its information-theoretically impossible to do it perfectly.